# How to loop over rows in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, loops, rows, postgis

I have two tables: `test_line` and `test_vertex`

Also I have the following query, which selects parts of `test_line` based on `test_vertex`. The query works fine if my two tables contain one row. Now I want to use the query for multiple rows. Is there a simple way two loop over the rows and applying the query, without changing too much from the original query?

```
 WITH
 lines as (SELECT wkb_geometry from test_line as geom),
 points as (SELECT geom from test_vertex as geom),
 numgeoms (pt_count) as (SELECT st_numgeometries(geom) + 1 as pt_count FROM points),
 knife_points as (
   SELECT x as segment, CASE WHEN x = 0 then 0
     WHEN x = (select pt_count from numgeoms) THEN 1 ELSE
     ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.wkb_geometry, ST_GeometryN(p.geom,x)) END as line_fraction_end,
     CASE WHEN x = 1 THEN 0  else
     ST_Line_Locate_Point(l.wkb_geometry, ST_GeometryN(p.geom,x-1)) END as line_fraction_start
   FROM points p, lines l, (SELECT generate_series(0, (SELECT pt_count from numgeoms)) as x ) g),
   segments as
    (SELECT ST_Line_Substring(wkb_geometry, line_fraction_start, line_fraction_end) as geom, segment
     FROM knife_points, lines WHERE segment >0 )
   SELECT geom, segment from segments
   WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) = 'ST_LineString';
```

Comment: You need to define where the multiple rows should come from exactly and how `test_line` and `test_vertex` are related and should be joined - unless you want a cross join for all possible combinations. As *always* your version of Postgres, please. Basic table definitions and sample data would almost be to much to wish for. Either way, you are not going to need a loop. You hardly ever need a loop with proper SQL.

Comment: I recognize this query :D I think you will need to add a WHERE ST_Intersects (a.geom, b.geom) and also possibly a GROUP BY.